# WP7: Understanding dark / light icons and how to change dynamically depending on thems (via mvvmlight)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, themes, mvvm-light, application-bar

From what I understand is that there is 2 themes in wp7, light and dark. I notice the application bar has generic images, they change to light or dark automatically.

But I placed a image from the SDK icons directory onto xml screen, I noticed they have 2 variants, light or dark.

Problem is that when I view the page with dark or light, the application bar buttons change according to the theme but the image doesn't.

Am I doing this right?

So do I have to check for a event change or something? So I know the theme has changed to automatically update the image from light to dark (or dark to light).

If this is the case, I am using mvvmlight and have my code behind quite clean, is this possible to do within the viewmodel or must it take place in the app.xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769545%28VS.92%29.aspx)

As of MVVMLight, you can detect current theme in MainViewModel constructor, or whichever main view model class you have.

Comment: And [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for full list of themed resources.